# CSS how to select all elements with a given class taht do not contain an element of another class

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

In the following code I would like to hide the button that has the `copy-button` class that does not contain an `<i>` element with the class `nice`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 
 .copy-button > :not([class*="nice"])
 {
   visiblility: hidden;
 }
 

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- I would like to see the following button... -->
<button class="copy-button">i contained<i class="cool nice"></i></button>

<!-- ... while I want this to be hidden -->
<button class="copy-button">i not contained</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to achieve it.

I would also be satisfied in hiding all the buttons that contain an , but this also does not work

```
 .copy-button > :not(i)
 {
   visiblility: hidden;
 }
```

How to achieve my result?

Thanks!

Comment: `.copy-button:has(i)` ?

Comment: Your question contradicts the code comments. The question says hide .copy-button **if no** i.nice child exists. The code comments say hide .copy-button if **there is a** i.nice child

Comment: You say you want to hide the button **that doesn't contain** the `i.nice`. But in the comment in your HTML you say you want to hide the button **that contains** `i.nice`... I'm confused :)

Comment: anyway also trying with `.copy-button:has(i)` that is somehow the negation of my condition i do not manage to hide the other button

Comment: sorry! i added the comments at the last moment and I did a boolean mistake. `.copy-button:not(:has(i.nice))` is what i need,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, like I and Zach Jensz already commented.
So in the following code I gave you both solutions.

```css
.copy-button:has(i.nice) {
  background: red;
}
.copy-button:not(:has(i.nice)) {
  background: blue; 
}
```

```html
<button class="copy-button">i contained<i class="cool nice"></i></button>

<button class="copy-button">i not contained</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the comments. `.copy-button:not(:has(i.nice))` is what I was looking for.